# Azure Maps Batch Geocoding Status 202 12+ Hours Later

Tags: c#, azure, restsharp, azure-maps

I'm using RestSharp to programmatically build/make/deserialize a call to the Azure Maps API for batch geocoding. Currently testing the process with a 5 address batch--something I expected to go quickly after all the posts about "10k addresses in minutes." But a request I make successfully yesterday is still not available, only showing the "Accepted 202" status that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/postsearchaddressbatchpreview) says means it's still processing...and there's no outage showing at the [status page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/).

I've replicated these calls and results using Postman, so I'm not sure there's a code problem per se...but it wouldn't be the first time I got tunnel vision and overlooked something obvious.

My POST call is generated with the code below, and returns an OK status with the necessary Location header with what looks like a valid link.

```
public RestRequest CreateBatchRequest()
{
    var request = new RestRequest($"{_batchAddressEndpoint}subscription-key={_apiToken}", Method.POST);
    request.AddQueryParameter("api-version", _version);

    var batchRequestBody = GenerateQueryBatch();

    var requestBodyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchRequestBody);

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("undefined", requestBodyJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    return request;
}

protected AzureBatchRequest GenerateQueryBatch()
{
    var requestBody = new AzureBatchRequest();

    foreach (var address in Addresses)
    {
        var addressString = $"{address.Address}, {address.City}, {address.State}";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_country))
            addressString = $"{address.Address}, {address.City}, {address.State}, {_country.ToUpper()}";

        requestBody.Queries.Add($"?query={addressString}&limit={_resultLimit}");
    }

    return requestBody;
}
```

This gives me a body parameter for the request that appears to match the documentation (actual addresses hidden for privacy reason, but they've been successfully geocoded with other services)...

```
{
    undefined={"queries":[
        "?query=123 MAIN ST, LOS ANGELES, CA&limit=3",
        "?query=123 MAIN ST, PLEASANTVILLE, CA&limit=3",
        "?query=123 MAIN ST, STOCKTON, CA&limit=3",
        "?query=123 MAIN ST, SAN DIEGO, CA&limit=3",
        "?query=123 MAIN ST, REDDING, CA&limit=3"
    ]}
}
```

I get the Location header value and make the GET call with it using the code below...

```
public List<Coordinate> DeserializeBatchResponse(RestResponse response)
{
    var batchLink = response.Headers.Where(header => header.Name.Equals("Location")).FirstOrDefault();

    var request = new RestRequest(batchLink.Value.ToString(), Method.GET);

    var batch = SendRequest(request);

    if (batch.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
    {
        var isProcessing = true;

        while (isProcessing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

            request = new RestRequest(batchLink.Value.ToString(), Method.GET);

            batch = SendRequest(request);

            if (batch.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                isProcessing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And it never leaves that loop. When I hardcode the URL returned from yesterday's POST request, it has the same behavior--as ditto when tried in Postman to isolate from the rest of my code.

Does anyone have any insight?

**UPDATE**

We discovered that after creating a new plan at a higher tier (the S1 rather than S0 tier) there was no noticeable delay on the batch calls. Still not a solution, per se, because that prices us out of the product for production purposes, but possibly a fix for others until the updates mentioned in the accepted answer come to fruition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected at the moment while in preview. This will be moving out of preview soon and will be significantly faster.

Comment: The team is also looking at a small update to preview to improve its performance while the production version is being completed.